# What is the feminine form of the word "maître" and its meaning?

Tags: professions

It is a profession and the masculine form of the word is "le maître"

Comment: Did you have a look in a dictionary? What did you find? Can you say why that din't help you? [maître](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/maitre?q=ma%C3%AEtre). Welcome fo French Language and please visit the Help Centre, particularly [this page](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you it helped

Answer (score 1):

There are different meanings for "maître". It can be used for a teacher in elementary school or the master of an animal. Then the feminine form is "maîtresse".

It is also used to refer to the master of some sport or art.

It can be used as a title for lawyers including [*avocats*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocat_(m%C3%A9tier)) ([advocates](https://www.britannica.com/topic/advocate)) and [*notaires*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaire) ([notaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary)). In that case, the title remains "[maître](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2779)" for both male and female lawyers.

Comment: Thank you so much...

Comment: What is a title for advocate? Do you mean a lawyer?

Comment: On *maître* being epicene as a title: there is this [story](https://www.dna.fr/societe/2020/07/28/appelez-moi-maitre-quand-gisele-halimi-recadrait-le-general-de-gaulle) of French lawyer Gisèle Halimi answering De Gaulle whether he should refer to her as Miss or Madam: "appelez-moi maître".

Comment: @Lambie [Advocate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advocate)

Comment: @jlliagre an advocate in English, **which you edited out of the answer**, is not un avocat. It is one of the most famous faux amis in translation.

Comment: @Lambie J'ai ajouté notaire et mis des mots français puisqu'on parle de professions françaises. Aucune des définitions proposées par le wiktionary ne me semble fondamentalement différente de celles utilisées avec le mot français. Le fait qu'on appelle pas un avocat *advocate* dans tel ou tel dialecte de l'anglais mais plutôt *barrister* ou *lawyer* ne signifie pas que le mot est invalide.  Dans certains pays du Commonwealth, le mot *advocate* semble le bon. Qui te dit que l'OP n'est pas indien ?  https://www.jagranjosh.com/general-knowledge/difference-between-advocate-and-lawyer-1539264726-1

Comment: @jlliagre No, by changing it you make my comment look bad. A lawyer in English is not an advocate. On ne dit pas advocate for avocat dans aucun dialecte de l'anglais. Barrister/solliciters are lawyers. Advocates are completely different. Advocates are people who support others for a particular reason. Nothing to do with lawyers.

Comment: J'ai simplement tenu compte de ton commentaire pour clarifier la réponse. [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-barrister-and-an-advocate) *Advocate refers to a legal practitioner in various countries. In Scotland, Advocates perform a role similar to that of Barristers in England, while in countries like South Africa, India, Pakistan, Bangladesh and Sri Lanka, which have a unified legal profession unlike the split legal profession described in the above paragraph, Advocate is a licensed lawyer who is entitled to act on behalf of clients and argue cases in Court.*

Comment: Scotland is an outlier. I can guarantee you that. In general, the French word avocat would not be translated by advocate. It would be just lawyer. And a notaire is not a lawyer even though they have to have a law degree. They cannot argue in a court of law. They can only draw up legal papers. Similar to a solliciter in the UK.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne parle pas de *common law* mais des professions où Maître est utilisé. En France, notaire et avocat sont des professions bien distinctes, mais un notaire français est bien un *lawyer* (c'est un [*civil law notary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_law_notary)). *As a **lawyer**, a civil-law notary draws up and executes legal instruments called notarial instruments*

Comment: @jlliagre Tu as changé le vocabulaire de la question. Je ne pense pas que cela soit éthique. //Non, un notaire français n'est pas un avocat.  Comme j'avais dit, les notaires ont de diplômes en droit,**mais n'ont pas le droit de plaider des causes dans les tribunaux**. (Cela fait 35 ans que je fais des traductions juridiques.)

Comment: @Lambie J'ai clarifié la réponse en remplaçant *advocate* qui pouvait prêter à confusion par "avocat" qui est ce que l'auteur de la réponse voulait dire et que tu avais sûrement compris. J'ai aussi enrichi la réponse en ajoutant "notaire" qui est un autre corps de métier dont les membres portent aussi le titre de *maître*, il y en a quelques autres. Je ne vois pas ce qu'il y aurait de non éthique là dedans. Je n'ai jamais écrit qu'un notaire était un avocat, en revanche, j'ai écrit qu'un notaire français est bien juridiquement un *lawyer* en fournissant une source que je t'invite à lire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127963/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Comment: Please note that maîtresse also has a different meaning. If you happen to once have a discussion with a former teacher of yours, and the next day you tell your friends "J'en discutais hier encore avec une ancienne maîtresse", this can turn funny :-)